# Regex - retrieve last n characters from a string if length exceeds maximum allowed length

Tags: regex, groovy

I have a field Notes and allowes only 240 characters. I want a regex to retrieve the last 240 characters if the user exceeds that limit. So, if he inserts 250 chars, I want the value to be the last 240 chars.
Is this possible or I need to use string functions to retrieve last 240 characters?

Now the regex is this:

```
/^(.{1,240})$/
```

Comment: You don't need the `^`, try matching `.{1,240}$`

Comment: Doing `^` and `$` together says Regex should match the full string, not only the end (just `$`). You could try `/(.{1, 240})$/`

Comment: Why do you want to use regex for this?

Comment: ooo, ok so I am using regex101 to test. It highlights the last characters. Nice, thank you.

Comment: Customer ERP field for max 240 characters but suppliers are still sending very long descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the start of string anchor ( ^ ) and try this

```js
let str = `I have a field Notes and allowes only 240 characters. I want a regex to retrieve the last 240 characters if the user exceeds that limit. So, if he inserts 250 chars, I want the value to be the last 240 chars. Is this possible or I need to use string functions to retrieve last 240 characters?

Now the regex is this: /^(.{1,240})$/`


let last240 = (str) => str.match(/[\s\S]{1,240}$/g)

console.log(last240(str))
```

***P.S. :-*** I changed regex pattern to `[\s\S]` to match new lines as well. if your requirement doesn't need this you just need to use `.{1,240}$`

Comment: No need for capturing group :) `$` fixes match at the end of the string and it's enough to get onyl matched string :) +1

Comment: The file validation runs with groovy, l will test without ^ , but will try the validation above. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about not using regex at all?

```
String lastN( String v, int n ){
  n < v.size() ? v.reverse().take( n ).reverse() : v
}

assert 'ef' == lastN( 'abcdef', 2 )
assert 'cdef' == lastN( 'abcdef', 4 )
assert 'abcdef' == lastN( 'abcdef', 42 )
```